# с++ что лучше? if или ?:

Tags: c++, операторы

Какой код будет лучше? Меня интересует, какой вариант будет лучше по скорости работы:

```
a == 60? b++:b;
или же
if(a == 60) b++;
```

Какой из операторов лучше?
Ещё было бы хорошо как-то в `a == 60? b++:b;` дописать так, чтобы сбросить переменную а до нуля.

Comment: Выбирайте тот, который понятнее человеку. Компилятор оптимизнёт как надо в большинстве случаев. Вообще, первая запись бредовенькая.

Comment: if лучше, тернарный оператор обычно путает людей, плюс у него с "приоритетами" немного по особому. Но можно и без if. Где то так  `b += (a==60);` Но в прод код  такое лучше не писать

Comment: Нужно компилировать и смотреть ассемблерный вывод. Вполне вероятно результат будет одинаков. Если результат получится разный, то нужно проводить тесты. Если тесты покажут, что способ `A` быстрее, чем способ `B`, это не гарантирует что в другом компиляторе/новой версии текущего/на другом процессоре расклад не изменится. Моё мнение: если разница в производительности и есть, то это экономия на спичках, которая в общем случае не нужна.

Comment: учитывая современные компиляторы и процессоры, гадать по ассемблерному коду о производительности очень сложно.

Comment: лично я бы не понял так быстро, что делает вариант сверху, нежели который снизу

Answer (score 7):

Оператор `?:` отличается от `if` тем, что у него есть возвращаемое значение одного типа.

```
int c = ( a == 60 ? ( a = 0 , b++ ) : ( a = 0 , b ) ) ;
```

А если возвращать нечего, тогда используйте `if`.

```
if (a == 60)
  b ++ ;
a = 0 ;
```

*Скорость тут ни причём.*

Самое главное понятность кода и без ошибок. Вот пример когда лучше использовать `?:` :

```
( a < b ? a : b ) = ( c > d ? c : d ) ;
```

*главное чтобы эти сравнения не зависили от порядка исполнения*

против :

```
if(a<b)
    if(c>d)
        a=c;
    else
        a=d;
else
    if(c>d)
        b=c;
    else
        b=d;
```

А вот так наверное не стоит :

```
a < b ? c < d ? x = 1 : y = 0 : d > c ? x = -1 : y = -2 ;
```

Comment: хочется прям поставить плашку "не является ответом на вопрос"

Comment: Ну, всё-таки как я и думал. Лучше if, так как у него есть полное тело, в котором можно спокойно выполнить множество операций. А второй вариант, думаю, изредка может пригодиться в частных случаях. Но и там его можно заменить с помощью if()

Comment: `function(A,B,(C?D:E),F,G,H)` или `if(C)function(A,B,D,F,G,H)else function(A,B,E,F,G,H)` - выбирайте

Comment: Так.. Это как-то слишком трудно, я пожалуй, останусь сторонником if)

Comment: Может так легче `*(a<b?&a:&b) = c+d+e+f;` <=> `if(a<b)a=c+d+e+f;else b=c+d+e+f;`

Comment: а зачем так писать?

Comment: Показываю разницу с `if`. Какую операцию выбирать и зачем. @KoVadim

Comment: @AlexGlebe вы молодцы!

Comment: Так тоже работает: `(a < b ? a : b) = c + d + e + f;`. Не надо брать адреса.

Comment: Согласен. Это я случайно в Си проверял, а там нет типа ссылка **(reference  type)**. @Stanislav Volodarskiy